# Microsoft Edge "unexpected call to method or property access" toLocaleDateString

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I've got a piece of Javascript code which says

```
var timeStamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

and it's been working for months.  Then, yesterday (16-Oct-2016) a user running the code provoked the error

> Unexpected call to method or property access

for this, and a similar line using `toLocaleDateString`.

It appears this user is running Microsoft Edge / Windows 10.  They say that in the past they have accessed the web site successfully.  The user agent string,

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393

is the same as my Edge / Windows 10, which works correctly.

They clearly have JavaScript execution enabled, because the code then invoked the onerror code, which wrote a copy of the error encountered into the server log file by JS, but I can't work out why we get the original error thrown.  On my system   new Date().toLocaleDateSTring() delivers the expected result (I know about the unprinted characters contained within the result)

Anyone know what has happened on this one site to make it fail here?

Some more information: I managed to run some test JavaScript on the target users' system and get them to send me the results.

```
var dateobj = new Date()
```

dateobj.toString() contains a sensibly formatted string with time and date.

```
dateobj.toLocaleTimeString()
```

fails. However

```
"toLocaleTimeString" in dateobj
```

returns true, and

```
typeof dateobj.toLocaleTimeString
```

is "function".

So why can't I call invoke it?

It runs fine on my system at the same spec (meaning: user-agent string matches - and other output from the navigator object). I have checked that they don't have any Edge extensions installed. What else can be affecting this?

Monathan

UPDATEED

Tried a few things in the JavaScript console on the target Edge browser... this is curious - it won't execute it -- but it is a function..?

> x=new Date()
>   [date] Wed Oct 26 2016 10:18:30 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
>   y=x.toLocaleDateString()
>   Error
>   x.toLocaleDateString
>   is a function ...

(See the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhpTL.png) for the actual detail)

Comment: Please open console of browser and check if the browser is in Quirks/compatibility mode. And try to execute that snippet of code separately.

Comment: Microsoft Edge doesn't (appear to have) compatibility modes I can play with?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem? I'm running into the same issue right now... :/

Comment: No, this is unresolved still.  Please let me know if you uncover anything.